# Trigger.io native drawer using viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, trigger.io

I am just starting off with Trigger.IO native modules and have this idea to create native drawer sliding from the left side.

I have no objective C experience, but I think I would get the main idea if someone could lead me in the right direction.

I think I should use viewController for this, but I can not find any examples how to make a basic appearance/disappearance functionality.

Comment: In case you're interested in a JS solution, take a look at https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js - the native solution sounds like a bit of work. good luck either way!

Comment: I have tried snap.js, but the problem was that to reveal 'drawer' which is behind 'content' container you have to drag 'content' and if you have a lot of divs inside that container slide animation becomes choppy...